# Comment out element when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use JavaScript to comment out a text within a div.

For example, I got `<div> This is a text</div>`. I want to use code so that unless this is visible, then it's commented out.

```
 <!-- -->
```

I got 3 tabs, which I can click to see a different text, image, video within the div.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6j6b7qq/) of what it looks like.

I tried changing the text and that's not so hard but I can't make a code that works the way I want. I want the hidden divs content to be commented out so as not to lag the site, but when I click on a hidden div I want the commented out part to be uncommented out.

This is the script used to switch and hide divs.

```
 $('.Options div').click(function() {
            var i = $(this).index();
            $('.Frames').hide();
            $('#Action' + (i + 1)).show();
        });
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="Options">       
                <div class="OptionsTab">OptionRed</div>
                <div class="OptionsTab">OptionGreen</div>
                <div class="OptionsTab">OptionBlue</div>
 </div>

 <div class="Holder">
                <div class="Frames" id="Action1" style="display: block;">

                 <div style="font-size: 25px; color: white;"> This is a contained object</div>  

                </div>
                <div class="Frames" id="Action2">

                    <div style="font-size: 25px; color: white;"> This is a contained object</div>

                </div>
                <div class="Frames" id="Action3">

                    <div style="font-size: 25px; color: white;"> This is a contained object</div>

                </div>





        </div>
```

Comment: Why? `display: none` would do the same thing as commenting it out.

Comment: @AmarSyla I've tested it with <iframe> video </iframe> and when I comment all but 1 out, the site loads instantly, when I use display:none on 10-15 tabs, it takes up to a minute. The <iframe> Video</iframe> runs in the background when using display:none

Comment: commenting out with javascript will not save you memory or loading time, as the sources have already been loaded from server

Comment: JavaScript works client-side: *after* the document's already been loaded. You should do this on the server-side, before it's sent to the client.

Comment: load the iframe when you click the tab.

Comment: @A.B Oh no, I meant load as in client side, computer performance.
I tried running it with 10+ videos, they all loaded at the same time and it put a strain on the computer, that's what I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: you can remove them with .remove() if you dont want just display:none;

Comment: @DavidThomas The load from server to site is no issue :) It's the performance of the device that I'm trying to improve.

Sushil I tried that in the past, but I wasn't trying to improve performance back then haha, thanks. I'll do that now and see what happens.

Comment: @A.B I'll try that :), just remembered doing that few months ago for something else so still got the code in my folder somewhere. Thx

Answer (score 1):

commenting out with javascript will not save you memory or loading time, as the sources have already been loaded from server

instead of hiding nodes with `hide()` (display:none) you can remove the nodes at client side by

```
$('.Frames').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use a some `data-` attribute for saving current inner html of element in `dataset`
2) Clear the current inner html of element with `$('your_selector').html(" ")`;
3) Return inner html from `data-` attribute into element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset